# Let $V$ be vector space of dimension $m\geq 2$. Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation such that $T^{n+1}=0 $ and $T^n\neq 0$ for some $n\geq 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ be vector space of dimension $m\geq 2$. Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation such that $T^{n+1}=0 $ and $T^n\neq 0$ for some $n\geq 1$. Then which of the following is necessarily TRUE?

(a). $Rank (T^n)\leq Nullity(T^{n+1})$

(b). $Trace(T)\neq 0$

(c). T is diagonalizable

(d). $n=m$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I think (a) is true
Nut I need counter examples for others

Answer (score 3):

(a) is true since $\ker T^{n+1}= V$.

(b) is false, since the  *minimal polynomial* of $T$ is $x^{n+1}$,  and the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues of $T$.

(c) is false, because $T$ is diagonalisable if and only if its minimal polynomial splits into a product of *distinct* linear factors.

(d) is false in general. Counter-example: $\;T=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies $\;n=1$. What is true is $\;n<m$.

Comment: So it is basically a nilpotent operator right?

Comment: That's in the hypothesis.